# Can baby zombies break down a door if only one block is placed in front?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a village near my base and to make sure zombies don't break into the houses, I put a block in front of each of the doors. But I'm not sure if that prevents baby villagers from breaking down the door or not. If there is only one block in front of the door, does it stop baby zombies from breaking down doors? And does it matter if the block is in front of the top or bottom part of the door? Also, does the orientation of the door affect whether or not they can break the door down?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, baby zombies can't break doors at all. I just tested having one aggro a villager through a wooden door, and the baby zombie did not break the door.

If you'd like to test it yourself, go into creative and test it using ' /summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {IsBaby:1} ' (The ~'s denote your current x,y, and z coordinates). Put him outside an enclosed building with a door, that has a villager in it.

Comment: I've seen baby zombies break down doors before, and I did a quick test in creative and they broke it down.

Comment: Also, the wiki doesn't say anything about baby zombies not being able to break down doors. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie

Comment: Interestingly enough no zombies can break down doors in my test world... Once I figure how to fix this, I'll edit my answer to see what's I find...

Comment: @Jonny Zombies break door only on hard difficulty

Comment: @Kcats Are you sure? I'm pretty sure I was playing on Normal when I saw a zombie break down my door.

Comment: That is what it says here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie#Attacking_Villagers - Zombies will bang on the door, but will not break it on easy or normal difficulty. Also there is a 'mobGriefing' gamerule that might also influence the Zombie behavior. I'm in no position to test these right now.

Comment: @Kcats Ah, didn't know that, good to know.

Comment: @Kcats Yes I'm aware that it only works on hard difficulty, but the thing is they aren't even hitting the doors to make the cracking sound, regardless of what difficulty I'm on. They are, however aggroing through the doors. I'll test the mobGrief flag, but I don't think that it's the problem, since flags are per world and it doesn't work on new worlds either.